# Python wont find certain things in csv files

Tags: python

```
import pyfiglet
import csv

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Menu   Program .")
print(ascii_banner)

start = str(input("1. Process an order.  2. View previous orders. 3. Edit Menu \nOption: "))

if start == "1":
    print("Welcome")
    with open('menu.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            print(row)
    fid = str(input("What is the food ID?"))
    if fid == row[1]:
        print(row[2])
    if fid != row[1]:
        print("That is not an id.")
```

My csv file:

```
foodname,fid,price
All day large,1,Five Pounds Fifty
All day small,2,Three Pounds Fifty
Hot Dog,3,Three Pounds
Burger,4,Four Pounds
Cheese Burger,5,Four Pound Twenty Five
Chicken goujons,6,Three Pounds Fifty
Fries,7,One Pound Seventy Five
Salad,8,Two Pound Twenty
Milkshake,9,Two Pound Twenty
Soft Drinks,10,One Pound Thirty
Still water,11,90 Pence
Sparkling water,12,90 Pence
```

When I run it, the program works if the input is 12 but any other number "isnt an id" which i find weird.
Does anybody know why this is and how i can fix it?

Comment: `row` holds values from the last line in your CSV file. Can you see why?

Comment: Not An idea, Im not good at this kind of thing I know the basics and im doing it for school

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), go over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and use [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) to help you visualize your code

Comment: What do you think ```row``` contains after you're done with the file?

Answer (score 0):

lets put `print(row)` after your `while` loop and before `fid` variable. What does it print? It prints out:

```
['Sparkling water', '12', '90 Pence']
```

That is because in your `while` loop you only printed `row`s one by one but didn't save them, so it only took the last one.

You guessed it then. That's why it only works if you type `12` as input.

The easiest way to solve this would be to convert your `reader` to `list` and put it in `row` variable. You can do it easily like this:

```
with open('menu.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        row = list(reader)
```

now if you `print(row)`, you will get a `2D list`:

```
[['foodname', 'fid', 'price'], ['All day large', '1', 'Five Pounds Fifty'], ['All day small', '2', 'Three Pounds Fifty'], ['Hot Dog', '3', 'Three Pounds'], ['Burger', '4', 'Four Pounds'], ... ]]
```

which means your `fid` is now at `row[1-12][1]` for every `menu` item and price on  `row[1-12][2]` etc. (`1-12` because at `0` is your column names foodname, fid and price)

To print the price from input first lets get `fid` from input:

```
fid = str(input("What is the food ID?"))
```

as you wrote returns a `str` and we want `int` so lets do it like this:

```
fid = int(input("What is the food ID?"))
```

Now to the main logic:

```
if fid > 0 and fid < len(row):
    print (row[fid][2])
```

First we check if `fid > 0` because thats where your column names are and then check if `fid` is in range to avoid `index out of range` `fid < len(row)`. If condition is met, then we print `row` at position `fid` and print its price which is at position `2` in your `csv`

So at the end your code should look like this.

```
import pyfiglet
import csv

ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Menu   Program .")
print(ascii_banner)

start = str(input("1. Process an order.  2. View previous orders. 3. Edit Menu \nOption: "))

if start == "1":
    print("Welcome")
    with open('menu.csv') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        row = list(reader)
    
    print(row)
    fid = int(input("What is the food ID?"))

    if fid > 0 and fid < len(row):
        print (row[fid][2])
    else:
        print ("That is not an id.")
```

To print items nicely I would add `print('\n'.join(map(' | '.join, row)))` instead of `print(row)` but I will leave that to you.

And please take a look at [CSV File Reading and Writing in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and for the future first try to solve your problem using [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and then If you really can't solve your problem, post it here.